# Why does successfully reading from a /dev source of data set errno?

Tags: c, linux, macos, stdio, errno

Simple test program in C called `get1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
    errno = 0;
    int ch = fgetc(stdin);
    printf("ch = %d\n", ch);
    if (errno)
        printf("errno = %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

It just prints the first byte read in decimal, and then shows `errno` and the associated error message if `errno` is not zero.

Some results (`foo` is a text file, `empty` is a file of length zero):

```
% ./get1 < foo
ch = 104
% ./get1 < empty
ch = -1
```

Ok, as expected. However:

```
% ./get1 < /dev/zero 
ch = 0
errno = 25: Inappropriate ioctl for device
% ./get1 < /dev/null 
ch = -1
errno = 25: Inappropriate ioctl for device
% ./get1 < /dev/random 
ch = 196
errno = 25: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

The read is working fine, but when I read from any of these devices it is setting `errno`. Why?

That was on macOS (Darwin). I get the same thing on Linux (Debian) and NetBSD, except a different error just for `/dev/random` (the errors on the other devices were the same as on macOS):

```
% ./get1 < /dev/random 
ch = 170
errno = 22: Invalid argument
```

It was my understanding that if you don't get `EOF`, then there is no error. If you do get `EOF`, then you check `errno` to see if there was an error. In all of these cases there does not appear to be an error in getting a byte from the device, nor should there be. Yet `errno` was set.

(Removing the `printf` doesn't change anything, in case anyone is wondering.)

As it turns out, `errno` is not set when reading from such a device on AIX, SunOS, or OpenSUSE.

So what's the deal here? Is this a bug, albeit widespread? Is this acceptable behavior? Is this *expected* behavior? Why is it setting `errno`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't have said it was *expected* behaviour (and indeed, I cannot reproduce it on the systems I have handy), but it is permitted by both the C standard and by Posix.

Both the C standard and Posix generally prohibit library functions from setting `errno` to 0, so they cannot clear `errno` to indicate success. However, C permits `errno` to be modified by a library function "whether or not there is an error, provided the use of `errno` is not documented in the
description of the function" (§7.5 para 3). The C standard does not document the use of `errno` by `fgetc`.

Posix is even more flexible: it specifies that

> The setting of errno after a successful call to a function is unspecified unless the description of that function specifies that errno shall not be modified.

It does document the use of `errno` by `fgetc`, but that documentation does not indicate that `errno` shall not be modified by a successful call, only that it should be modified by a read error.

Specifically, what Posix says is

> If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, `fgetc()` shall return `EOF`, and shall set `errno` to indicate the error.

In other words, `EOF` might indicate a *successful call* (because end of file is not an error) or it might indicate an error. Only in the latter case is `errno` set to a meaningful value. Consequently, before checking `errno` you need to verify that `ferror(stdin)` reports an error.

So, as I said, the behaviour is allowed by the standards. Why does the `fgetc` implementation do that? My guess is that the `libc` implementations on your systems are doing some sort of lazy initialization on the first call.

Comment: Incorrect. The Posix standard says that `getchar()` is equivalent to `fgetc()`, and [`fgetc()` does document the use of `errno`, specifically that it shall set `errno` if there is a read error](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). Just to be pedantic, I changed it to `fgetc()` and got the same behaviors.

Comment: In fact, since it behaves the same, I changed the source code in the question to use `fgetc()`.

Comment: @MarkAdler: Yes, it defers the documentation to `fgetc` but it still documents it. But the documentation does not say that `errno` is not modified on success. What it says is that if an error occurs, the stream's error error indicator will be set, and it is that fact -- rather than the return of EOF -- which should cause you to inspect `errno`.

Comment: Ah, ok, _that's_ the answer to my question. I should check `ferror(stdin)` first. If I do that, I see that there is no error.

Comment: @MarkAdler: I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: By the way, with regard to your deleted answer, the C standard says that `errno` shall be set to zero at the start of execution. So my `errno = 0` was not necessary.

Comment: @MarkAdler: Yes, that's one of the reasons I deleted that answer. I'm sure I've seen errno set by a library initializer, though; perhaps that is a bug. Or perhaps its a bug in my memory.

Answer (score 4):

The `errno` is not result of the specific operation but rather result of supporting operation when building high level `FILE *stdin` stdio structure.

Libc usually calls `stat()`, few others and `lseek()` system call which fails because the specific files in `/dev/` are not regular files. It may depend on specific Libc implementation, therefore the differences you saw on various systems.

This doesn't mean that your operation failed though, you should check errno only in case error code is returned.

On Linux you can use command `strace` to get the list of all system calls your program is calling and the exact one causing the errno:

```
strace ./my program
```

There are similar tools on the other systems too.

Comment: *you should check errno only in case error code is returned.* There are some exceptions to this rule: overflow can only be detected in `strtol()` and friends by setting `errno` to `0` before the call and comparing it to `0` after the call.

Comment: @chqrlie We can't use `char **endptr` to detect overflow? Something like `if *ptr in [0..9]`?

Comment: @Stargateur: a number can overflow without having too many digits.

Comment: @rici Never mind, `strtol()` parse all digits even with overflow because there are not invalid character.

Comment: If I _don't_ do the `getchar()`, then I `errno` is _not_ set. So it is most definitely the `getchar()` that is ultimately causing `errno` to be set, regardless of the details of the unfortunate series of events that resulted in that.

Comment: @MarkAdler : definitely, the FILE structure initialization is done as part of first read call on stdin. Which is getchar in this case.

Comment: Furthermore, the POSIX standard states clearly that `errno` shall be set if `fgetc()` has a read error the return value shall be `EOF`. (It also states that `getchar()` is equivalent to `fgetc()`. I can change the `getchar()` to `fgetc(stdin)` and get the same behavior.) Note that in the `/dev/null` case it is returning `EOF`, in which case I should be checking `errno`.